# XML Serialization within derived class

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, deserialization

I am looking to tidy up the classes I use to hold my xml data prior to de/serialization.

What I am trying to  get to is this

```
<CalculationInputs>
  <Key Name="Keyname" Value="keyname" />
  <Input Name="InputName" Value="InputValue" />
  <Input Name="InputName2" Value="InputValue2" />
</CalculationInputs>
```

My current implementation involves having a 'CalculationInputs' class with a List of 'Input' and a single Key type i.e.

```
[XmlRoot("CalculationInputs")]
public class CalculationInputs
{
...

[XmlElement("Key")]
public Key Key { get; set; }

// InputList
[XmlElement("Input")]
public List<Input> InputList { get; set; }

...

}
```

However I wanted to stream line this by having the list CalculationInputs class like this

```
[XmlRoot("CalculationInputs")]
        public class CalculationInputs: List<Input>
        {
            [XmlElement("Key")]
            public Key Key { get; set; }
...
}
```

Sadly it only 50% works. The extended list desearilizes fine.. but the 'Key' element is just ignored and I get this

```
<CalculationInputs>
  <Input Name="InputName" Value="InputValue" />
  <Input Name="InputName2" Value="InputValue2" />
</CalculationInputs>
```

Anyone got any pointers?

Also, for extra points - when deserializing I can have many Key tags and it uses the first and ignores the rest i.e.

```
  <Key Name="Keyname" Value="keyname" />
  <Key Name="Keyname2" Value="keyname2" />
```

Whereas for me it'd be better if an exception was thrown when deserialing this as Key is not a List.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

**c#**

```
 [XmlRoot("CalculationInputs")]
  public class CalculationInputs
   {

  [XmlElement("Key")]
  public Key Key { get; set; }

  // InputList
  [XmlArray("array")]
  [XmlArrayItem("Input")]
  public List<Input> Input { get; set; }
  }
    public class Key
    {
        [XmlAttribute("Name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute("Value")]
        public string Value { get; set; }
     }
    public class Input
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Value { get; set; }
    }
```

**And change your Xml like below**

```
<CalculationInputs>
  <Key Name="Keyname" Value="keyname" /> 
  <array>
  <Input Name="InputName" Value="InputValue" />
  <Input Name="InputName2" Value="InputValue2" />
  </array>
</CalculationInputs>
```

Comment: It is not obvious how this helps? You aren't using a derived class, infact the suggested class is more complex that the class I am trying to replace - as is the outputted xml.